# Convert PLSQL script in Unix?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql, ksh

Is possible convert this PL-SQL code to unix code?

```
declare
   tipE varchar(8) := 'TEST';
begin
insert into TABLENAME VALUES (values);
   if tipExec = 'TEST' then
      dbms_output.put_line('INSERT is ok; called ROLLBACK in '' TEST');
      ROLLBACK;
   end if;

  exception
    when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
      if tipE = 'TEST' then
         raise_application_error(-9999, 'DUPKEY in'' TEST');
      else
         raise;
      end if;
    when others then
      raise;
end;
```

Is it possible? I mean i have a parameter "test" or "prod". I have to make an insert and if this insert has a DUPKEY i have to write it in a log. Otherwise i'll write in the log "INSERT is ok". And the code above it's almost the same concept but in oracle. I need this in unix shell. Thanks.

Comment: 'make an insert' where - you mean call SQL*Plus to do the insert from a shell script, and log the success/failure message to a file from there? (And why `when others then raise`? That seems pointless).

Comment: `"do the insert from a shell script, and log the success/failure message to a file from there?"` Yes!

Comment: Starting from this code if possible.. This is what i want but in ksh

Comment: Which Unix shell?  Bourne?  bash?  posix?  Korn?  C shell?  ash? You'll need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Yes, you're right...However ksh

Answer (score 0):

Create your program above as a named PL/SQL procedure, and then you can easily just invoke it from sqlplus via a Unix shell script like this:

```
sqlplus -s $USERPASS  << sqlend
    whenever sqlerror exit 1
    set heading off
    exec your_function('$example_variable');
sqlend
```

...where $USERPASS is your login mechanism / user&password. If you dont use any function parameters just delete that bit in the brackets.

Have a look at this Oracle tutorial for an example of how to create a procedure from your PLSQL code snippet:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21plsql-242570.html

As a starter, your procedure should look something like this (un-tested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE your_function
IS
   tipE varchar(8) := 'TEST';
begin
insert into TABLENAME VALUES (values);
   if tipExec = 'TEST' then
      dbms_output.put_line('INSERT is ok; called ROLLBACK in '' TEST');
      ROLLBACK;
   end if;

  exception
    when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
      if tipE = 'TEST' then
         raise_application_error(-9999, 'DUPKEY in'' TEST');
      else
         raise;
      end if;
    when others then
      raise;
end your_function;
```

Comment: But i haven't understand how invoke the procedure via shell script. (ksh unix shell). What i have to write to invoke it? Because my block is an a"nonymous" block and as you know, it haven't got a name. I've never worked with this type of blocks sorry.

Comment: I have added some more which should make it clearer what you need to do.